# Refactor multiple gsub statements into 1

Tags: ruby, gsub

Trying to refactor this into one line to get all vowels in a string to be capitalized. I tried using a hash, but that failed. Still too new at Ruby to know of any alternatives, despite my best efforts to look it up. something like.... `str.gsub!(/aeiou/`

```
def LetterChanges(str)
  str.gsub!(/a/, "A") if str.include? "a"
  str.gsub!(/e/, "E") if str.include? "e"
  str.gsub!(/i/, "I") if str.include? "i"
  str.gsub!(/o/, "O") if str.include? "o"
  str.gsub!(/u/, "U") if str.include? "u"
  puts str
end
```

Comment: +1 for asking the question in proper way.........

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is

```
str.tr('aeiou', 'AEIOU')
```

[`String#tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-tr)

> Returns a copy of `str` with the characters in `from_str` *replaced by the corresponding characters* in `to_str`. If to_str is shorter than from_str, it is padded with its last character in order to maintain the correspondence.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of string#tr but I will definitely use that. Much appreciated!

Comment: @NateBeers Enjoy Ruby... :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub)'s second parameter, which is a replacement hash:

```
str.gsub!(/[aeiou]/, 'a' => 'A', 'e' => 'E', 'i' => 'I', 'o' => 'O', 'u' => 'U')
```

or, alternatively, pass a block:

```
str.gsub!(/[aeiou]/, &:upcase)
```

Both will return:

```
'this is a test'.gsub!(/[aeiou]/, 'a' => 'A', 'e' => 'E', 'i' => 'I', 'o' => 'O', 'u' => 'U')
# => "thIs Is A tEst"

'this is a test'.gsub!(/[aeiou]/, &:upcase)
# => "thIs Is A tEst"
```

Comment: write as `str.gsub(/[aeiou]/, &:upcase)` if you want...  :-)